# Can you allow creation of new tags and commenting with lower reputation?

Tags: feature-request, tagging, tags, comments

Can you allow users to create new tags and comment with just ten or fifteen points?

As a new user it's hard to use this site if I can't tag properly or comment.

Comment: You can always comment on your own questions, if I remember correctly.

Comment: FYI, I deleted your [answer on another post](http://meta.ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/159/how-long-will-it-be-before-this-site-is-closed-if-we-dont-start-getting-more-q), because it was the same as this question. You did the right thing by starting a new question; the answer just clutters up the other question. Hang in there! You'll get there. :)

Comment: One reason that this site is in beta is that we have to get enough users with enough rep to create tags etc, The limits on what you can do are because if too low then we can be spammed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to comment on your own questions, regardless of reputation. The reputation thresholds for commenting on other posts and creating tags, however, are set by the Stack Exchange network and cannot be changed for just this site.

Right now, the site is not so busy that your question will be lost if it doesn't have the perfect tags. It will be seen by plenty of people, even if the tags aren't quite right. Besides, other users will probably add any necessary tags for you by editing your question.

So, feel free to ask your questions, and don't worry too much about the details! If you ask good questions, you'll get to the reputation thresholds soon enough, anyway.

Comment: by the way, are you  the editor.

Comment: Yes. I didn't change anything substantive about your question; I just tweaked the grammar and spelling a bit. For example, we typically use "you" instead of "u."

Comment: Oh. i was wondering why i see your name allover and you have so much "points"

Comment: Well, I am [one of three moderators](http://meta.ebooks.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and was one of the site's first members. [There are others with more reputation than I have](http://meta.ebooks.stackexchange.com/users)!

Comment: i ment hired by the website owner, not a badge.

Comment: Oh. No, I am not an employee. I am an ordinary user, but I [help run this particular site as a volunteer, at least until moderator elections are held](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators).